# Second level inheritance at JPA with TABLE_PER_CLASS

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, eclipselink

I could not make it work to use second level inheritance...

Have anybody experience in this topic?
Maybe a hint?

I forced to use other Inheritance strategy?:/

**FileEntity class**

> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> @Table(name = "file_entity", schema = "", catalog = Constants.CATALOG_NAME)
> public class FileEntity {
> ...
> }
> ```

**Document class**

> ```
> @Entity
> @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
> @Table(name = "document", schema = "", catalog = Constants.CATALOG_NAME)
> public class Document extends FileEntity {
> ...
> }
> ```

**Mail class**

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "mail", schema = "", catalog = Constants.CATALOG_NAME)
> public class Mail extends Document
> ```

Got the following exception with no filled Exception Description in it..

```
Descriptor Exceptions: 
Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)

Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareOneToOneSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareChildrenSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.initialize(OneToOneMapping.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.initialize(ClassDescriptor.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.isLockableMapping(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.postInitialize(ClassDescriptor.java:3808)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)

[EL Config]: connection: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Connection(486777790)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--disconnect
[EL Finer]: cache: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--initialize identitymaps
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--file:/C:/Users/Péter/workspace/applicLiquidator.trunk/target/classes/_liquidator logout successful
[EL Config]: connection: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Connection(1860920268)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--disconnect
[EL Severe]: ejb: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)

Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareOneToOneSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.TablePerClassPolicy.prepareChildrenSelectionQuery(TablePerClassPolicy.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.initialize(OneToOneMapping.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.initialize(ClassDescriptor.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.isLockableMapping(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1092)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.postInitialize(ClassDescriptor.java:3808)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)

[EL Finest]: jpa: 2014-11-28 12:40:52.183--ServerSession(2146583186)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End deploying Persistence Unit liquidator; session file:/C:/Users/Péter/workspace/applicLiquidator.trunk/target/classes/_liquidator; state DeployFailed; factoryCount 1
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [liquidator] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createDeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.initEntityManager(CsvImporter.java:42)
    at liquidator.util.external.csvimport.CsvImporter.main(CsvImporter.java:28)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28019] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Deployment of PersistenceUnit [liquidator] failed. Close all factories for this PersistenceUnit.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.deployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:238)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.initializeDescriptors(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.postConnectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but shouldn't you set the InheritanceType only at the root Entity?

Comment: Tried already (but thanks), the exception is the same.

Comment: As far as i can see, there is nothing absolutely wrong with your inheritance strategy. Can you try to use another jpa provider like Hibernate/OpenJPA and confirm if it does not work? It seems to me this may just be eclipselink issue. Eclipselink may be getting confused when you specify the table name and the TABLE_PER_CLASS strategy. You may remove the explicit table name to confirm the scenario too, and let the jpa provider generate the table names (for test of course)

Comment: Thank you very much maress!
I will try it in these week, and get back to this topic!

Comment: Unfortunatly not anymore working on that project, so could not try the other JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

Have u probe to use one discriminator value for inherited tables ?, for example:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", 
                     discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)  <== In the the super class
@DiscriminatorValue("FileEntity")
FileEntity 

@DiscriminatorValue("Document ")
Document
```

Comment: I think DiscriminatorValue and Column has no use when i choose NOT TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy. If i am right the SINGLE_TABLE strategy use Discriminator.